# How to create a http response for images in java?

Tags: java, image, http, webserver, response

I have been trying to create a simple java web server everything works fine for files such as html or css but I'm unable to send image responses correctly. The problem is obviously with the image data that I'm sending but I'm not sure how to do it properly. I have been searching for any information about it for a long time not and I just can't find anything useful that would fix my problem.

Part of my code:

```
public void Send(String path) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists()) {
        if(!file.isDirectory()) {
            if(isImage(file)) {
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF + "Content-Length: " + bytes.length + CRLF;
                response += "content-type: image/jpeg" + CRLF + CRLF;
                outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.write((CRLF + CRLF).getBytes());
                outputStream.flush();
            } else {
                String data = "";
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String st;
                while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    data += st;
                }
                int length = data.getBytes().length;
                String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF + "Content-Length: " + length + CRLF;
                response += CRLF + data + CRLF + CRLF;
                br.close();
                outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    SendError("404 Not Found");
}
```

> outputStream is OutputStream from a Socket.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956849/how-to-create-a-http-response-sending-an-image-in-java) but I think I'm only using streams at least for the image part.

I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT (more inforamtion):

Browser information:

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utS6r.png)

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT6Lz.png)

The isImage(file) methode works fine I have tested it but here it is:

```
private boolean isImage(File file) {
    String mimetype = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file);
    String type = mimetype.split("/")[0];
    return type.equals("image");
}
```

And the image is 2.jpg

EDIT 2

I wrote this code to write the content of the array in a text file:

```
String out = "";
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    if(i%16 == 0) {
        out += "\n";
    }
    out += String.format("%02X ", bytes[i]);
}
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
writer.write(out);
writer.close();
```

So I checked the start of both the image and the array and they seem to be identical.

[Start of the image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/660QB.png)

[Start if the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIonC.png)

After that I tried to create a client for testing:

```
private static void Get2(String link) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.68");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
    con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "no-cors");
    con.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "image");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "sl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7");
    
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    con.setReadTimeout(5000);
    
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    
    int status = con.getResponseCode();
    
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 0;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if(i < 5) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        } else {
            content.append(inputLine);
        }
        i++;
    }
    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test2.txt"));
    writer.write(content.toString());
    writer.close();
}
```

> I called the function: Get2("http://localhost:8080/images/2.jpg");

And got saved data in the test2.txt. Inside I saw some parts of similar data but it's clearly something wrong with it. I'm not sure if I'm using this client test wrong so if I'm doing something wrong or should be using something else let me know.

[Image (left test2.txt, right test.txt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia4Ro.png)

Thanks to everyone that will and already helped or had any suggestions.

Comment: What happens when you use this code? does any error show up in the browser console? Did you look at what the response looks like in the developer tools network tab (if available)? Also, I'm unsure of how the `isImage` method works and when exactly does it return true, but are you sure you're using a JPEG image?

Comment: I added additional information to the main post.

Comment: You probably do not need this for image: outputStream.write((CRLF + CRLF).getBytes());

Comment: I removed it. Doesn't change much though as far as I can tell.

Comment: The response looks correct in the image you provided, length of nearly 100 thousand bytes seems okay for an image, this means that the browser is receiving some content, or a part of it, the problem is therefore probably in the bytes you're sending, you could possibly dump the content of `byte[] bytes` into some file in a human-readable format (e.g. bytes as hexadecimal values) but this would probably waste a lot of your time, but it's the only idea that comes to my mind right now, don't forget to `close()` the `InputStream` too

Comment: Or you could just check the first byte of the array and check if it matches with the one of the image, that would probably be the much easier than checking the whole file

Comment: Thanks, I closed the `InputStream `. And I tried to do as many tests as you suggested.

Comment: Try serving the file from a common web server (you can probably quickly do it in tomcat) and compare the output from theirs and yours. F12 in browser shall help alot. It could be that the content type that your server is returning is not accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I finally figured it out. Actually my bad for not providing everything.</strike>

> String CRLF = "\n\r";

But apparently, it should only be \n.

I read somewhere that windows automatically adds \r after \n. I don't know if that's true but removing \r fixed my problem as before I had 2 empty lines right after `GET / HTTP/1.1` so the other content was considered as part of the data.

As soon as I changed that everything worked fine.
Again thanks for your help!

EDIT

Nevermind. What I did wrong was the order of \n and \r. It should be `\r\n` not `\n\r`